# Type '' is not assinable to type never[]

Tags: angular

```
loadCartItems() {
    this.cartService.getCartItems().subscribe(
        (items: CartItem[]) => { this.cartItems = items; }
    )
}
```

The code above gives me the error message `Type 'CartItem[]' is not assignable to type 'never[]'. Type 'CartItem' is not assignable to type 'never'.`

I have tried to find a solution but have been unsuccessful. What is causing this error?

here's my cart.service

```
@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class CartService {

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }

  getCartItems(): Observable<CartItem[]> {

    return this.http.get<CartItem[]>(cartUrl).pipe(
      map((result: any[]) => {
        let cartItems: CartItem[] = [];
```

Comment: Can you show me cartService code?

Comment: ı try to edit it but ı really dont know how to do it properly ıt doesnt contain the whole service thank you for trying to be helpful!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you should change code like this.

```js
return this.http.get<CartItem[]>(cartUrl)
```

Or, if you edit result from API you should change like this.

```js
    return this.http.get<CartItem[]>(cartUrl).pipe(
      map((result: CartItem[]) => {
        const editResult = result
        // edit editResult
        return editResult 
      })
```